# Conditional transposing a data frame

Tags: r

Here is the data I have:

```
  # A tibble: 12 x 6
   X1    X2             revenue   concentration   payroll    empl    
   <chr> <chr>          <int>            <dbl>    <int>      <int>   
 1 22    UTILITIES       NA               NA      NA          NA      
 2 NA    A              411713327        100     594684702   703
 3 NA    B              60450109         14.7    89399263    565 
 4 NA    C              94267425         22.9    62051796    221 
 5 NA    D              167024533        40.6    735288219   583
 6 NA    E              265695265        64.5    406753391   541
```

And what I want is the following

```
 X1    X2             A.revenue     B.revenue    C.Revenue A.concentration B.concentration C.concentration   A.payroll B.payroll C.Payroll    A.empl B.empl C.empl     
   <chr> <chr>          <int>            <dbl>    <int>      <int>   
 1 22    UTILITIES       411713327  60450109     9426742       100   14.7   22.9    40.6    64.5            etc.etc...
```

I know that there is no enough explaination, but I hope that it seems understandable.

Comment: You should post `dput(tbl)`. You should also indicate whether the problem is larger than this, i.e. whether there are going to be multiple values of X1 that each need to be rearranged,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is general enough, but as @42 comments, we could use a more extensive description of the issue:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(X2b = ifelse(!is.na(X1),X2,NA)) %>%
  fill(X1,X2b) %>%
  filter(!is.na(revenue)) %>%
  gather(,,-c(X1,X2,X2b)) %>%
  unite(key,key,X2,sep=".") %>%
  spread(key,value)
# 
# X1       X2b concentration.A concentration.B concentration.C concentration.D concentration.E empl.A empl.B empl.C empl.D empl.E
# 1 22 UTILITIES             100            14.7            22.9            40.6            64.5    703    565    221    583    541
# payroll.A payroll.B payroll.C payroll.D payroll.E revenue.A revenue.B revenue.C revenue.D revenue.E
# 1 594684702  89399263  62051796 735288219 406753391 411713327  60450109  94267425 167024533 265695265
```